# CREATE VIEW with SELECT results from CTE

Tags: sql-server, view, common-table-expression

I'm having the hard time creating a `VIEW` with the results of the `SELECT` statement from my `CTE`.  The following is my syntax:

```
    CREATE VIEW fooView AS
    ;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT a, b, c, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b, c ORDER BY a) AS RN
    FROM foo)
    SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

I have also tried this which also doesn't work:

```
    ;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT a, b, c, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTTION BY a, b, c ORDER BY a) AS RN
    FROM foo)
    CREATE VIEW fooView AS
    SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Anybody want to help me out with this?

Comment: I think you want this : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7239/transact-sql-using-with-in-create-view

Comment: What is the error message? Did you realize you didn't spell PARTITION correctly? Also, you have a statement terminator in your view, a view is not allowed to have more than 1 statement. This is a common misconception about ctes. The semicolon is a statement termintor, not a statement beginninator. Remove the semicolon and spell partition correctly and this should work.

Comment: @SeanLange LOL at "beginninator". Will have to use that from now on.  Took away the semicolon and worked.  Thanks

Comment: It isn't my creation, that belongs to Lynn Pettis from sqlservercentral but it is might funny!!